# Where can I ask questions about the BeagleBone Black?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask questions about the beagle bone black and programming issues for it?

I've been thinking of buying a beagle bone black which will be able to get android or Linux installed on it. I heard programming a cortex chip is quite difficult compared with Arduino etc. and thought I'd check some questions from others first.

But when I did that on electronics engineering I found just a few questions and barely an answer on it.

(I'm about to create a new boardcomputer for a solar boat.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the programming side, Stack Overflow is the right place. There are some 300 questions tagged [BeagleBone Black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beagleboneblack).

For the hardware design part, I don't see why EE would't be a fit. Currently 40 questions under [BeagleBone Black](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beaglebone-black?page=1&sort=newest&pagesize=15), approx. 80% of which have at least one answer. (The also take programming questions as long as they are about [*writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications*](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)

Comment: Oh, right. I've been selecting the wrong search type. I've been searching for titles with beagle bone on it instead of searching for beagle bone tags. Thanks!